# You will be able to see me

Tags: riddle

**The clues for the riddle are below:**

1. If you walk outside.. you will be able to see me
2. If you look into the ocean.. you will be able to see me
3. If you look into space (with a telescope), you will be able to see me
4. I am some people's favorite thing.. but a sad thing to others

*What am I?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could the answer be:

> blue

Reasoning being:

> When you walk outside, you can see the blue sky, when you look into the ocean, you can see the color blue, when you look into space with a telescope, you can see blue objects (some planets, other celestial objects), and the color blue is favorite to some people, but represents sadness to others?

Comment: You are a genius!

Comment: Thanks @FairOPShotgun It's my first shot at this stack exchange website. Glad it went well, haha.

Comment: That is awesome!